# What makes the amide bond the lowest energy pathway?

Tags: energy, mass-spec

I've reading about proteomics and how it can be used with mass spectrometry to sequence digested peptides.

Reading this [paper](http://www.nature.com/nrm/journal/v5/n9/full/nrm1468.html) the author states (in box 2):

> peptide fragmentation induced by collisions with residual gas, and
>   bond breakage mainly occurs through the lowest energy pathways - that
>   is, cleavage of the amide bonds

Why is cleavage predominately at the amide bond? What makes the amide bond the lowest energy pathway?

Comment: This question is probably better suited to Chemistry.SE

Comment: @MattDMo While this is a chemistry question, it is also about biologically important molecules, so it is still on-topic here.

Comment: @MadScientist Even though it is about a biological relevant molecule the principle behind this question is chemistry. Note that this is not about peptide formation and degradation in-vivo; it is about collision induced decay (nothing biological here).